reverse list using recursion in python3
Why this code doesn't work as expected?
I know there are other ways to reverse list using recursion
but I am interested particularly in why this method doesn't work.
def reverse(nums):
    if len(nums) < 2:
        return
    nums[0], nums[-1] = nums[-1], nums[0]
    reverse(nums[1:-1])


A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
reverse(A)
print(A)

I am expecting the output [6 5 4 3 2 1]. Instead, I am getting [6 2 3 4 5 1].

You create a copy of the sub-list, then "reverse"  that, without changing the original list (except for the first and last element)

With reverse(nums[1:-1]) you create a copy of the sub-list, then "reverse" that, without changing the original list (except for the first and last element). Instead, you should pass the original list together with the next index to change, e.g. something like this:
def reverse(nums, i=0):
    if i >= len(nums) // 2:
        return
    nums[i], nums[-1-i] = nums[-1-i], nums[i]
    reverse(nums, i+1)

Of course, for all practical applications you should use a slice with negative step A = A[::-1] or the builtin function A = list(reversed(A)).

I am just practicing DSA..
I prefer iteration over recursion in practical applications.
Also slicing really creates a new copy of the sub list or it just does pointer manipulation?

@Neeraj You are right, both of the "practical" ways would create a reversed copy of the list and not reverse it in-place.

I like your approach and @tobias_k points out the issue. I think you may enjoy this alternative solution -
def reverse(t):
  if len(t) < 2:
    return t
  return t[-1] + reverse(t[1,-1]) + t[0]

print(reverse(A))


The issue lies in how you're applying recursion.  Each recursive call focuses on a shrinking sublist (nums[1:-1]), which does swap the first and last elements of that sublist. However, these swaps are happening in isolation and don't propagate the changes back up to the original list.
Every time you shrink the list, you pass a copy of it, and when you do the flip, you technically doing that flip in the local copy of the list that you passed.
so you should pass the list itself not a copy of it!
This is a functioning version of your function:
def reverse(nums):
    def _reverse(nums, start, end):
        if start >= end:
            return
        nums[start], nums[end] = nums[end], nums[start]
        _reverse(nums, start + 1, end - 1)

    _reverse(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1)

